# Cardview not at back position in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-relativelayout

I have problem with implement CardView in RelativeLayout. I set CardView at back position in RelativeLayout. But it's seem not which I want.

I want like this (edited by photosop):
[image]

Current Display (on live Device and on android studio)
[image]

this the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/root_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layout_isi"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_isi"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/layout_isi"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layout_isi"/>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_isi"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_business_name_child">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_widthPercent="75%">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_thumbnail_business"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_widthPercent="50%">

                <com.kamardagang.utils.ResizeImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail_business"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_thumbnail_business"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_widthPercent="50%">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
                        android:id="@+id/icon_status_rating"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                        android:text="@string/fa_minus_circle" />

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/business_rating"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|center" />

                    <com.kamardagang.utils.TimesNewRomansTextView
                        android:id="@+id/status_rating"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="status_rating" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <com.kamardagang.utils.TimesNewRomansTextView
                    android:id="@+id/business_title"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="business_title"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <com.kamardagang.utils.TimesNewRomansTextView
                    android:id="@+id/business_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="business_name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <com.kamardagang.utils.TimesNewRomansTextView
                    android:id="@+id/business_status"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:text="business_status"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%">

            <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconButton
                android:id="@+id/count_rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#337ab7"
                android:text="@string/star"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconButton
                android:id="@+id/view_rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lihat_rating" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/layout_business_name_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#337ab7"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    <com.kamardagang.utils.TimesNewRomansTextView
        android:id="@+id/business_name_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="business_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I also implemnted `View.bringToFront();`, but it's not work, so how to fix it ? sory for my English

Comment: I see you're using RelativeLayout (more: PercentRelativeLayout), but you don't set positions to elements. I mean for example - button should be on the right with big margins which made them more centered

Comment: please read `Positioning Views` in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: i have not idea again, what the atribut i use to fix it, can you tell me?

Comment: read article above. Only CardView has alignment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/root_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_business_name_child"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_isi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_business_name_child"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

            <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_widthPercent="75%">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_thumbnail_business"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="50%">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_business"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_thumbnail_business"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="50%">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/icon_status_rating"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                            android:text="Test" />

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/business_rating"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/status_rating"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text="status_rating" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/business_title"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="business_title"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/business_name"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="business_name"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/business_status"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        android:text="business_status"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_widthPercent="25%">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/count_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#337ab7"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/view_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/layout_business_name_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#337ab7">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/business_name_child"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="business_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I put the `PercentRelativeLayout` within the `CardView` and it worked.

Hope this helps :)